# Do I need multiple gateways for multiple database connections

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I want to create two reports in two separate workspaces. Both reports use data from different SQL Server databases. Do I need separate gateways for that? From my understanding, I can use the same gateway for multiple database connections, so what is the advantage of having different gateways? What is the best practice?

Does the answer depend on the following scenarios?

1. Report A uses database A from the SQL server x.x.x.x:xx and report B uses database B in the same sql server
2. Report A and Report B use different database from different sql servers